# C# Error with Read Only assignment

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF C# project that I am moving to Visual Studio 2013.

The following code had compiled OK, but now it is failing:

```
CultureInfo origCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(DILData.GetString("Config_Locale"));
```

The following is declared:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

The error is:

> Property or indexer 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

I did not have this problem before.  What is it missing?

Comment: What version of .Net are you building against? That property is read-only previous to 4.6, according to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are compiling the project against an old .NET Framework version. Try to set it to .NET 4.6 or higher.

> In the .NET Framework 4.5.2 and earlier versions, the CurrentCulture
>   property is **read-only**; that is, you can retrieve the property value,
>   but you cannot set it. [..] Starting with the .NET Framework 4.6, the CurrentCulture property is **read-write**; you can both set and retrieve the property's value

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Super.  Thanks for being so quick.  That fixed it immediately.  I think the ported project was originally 4.5.3 but for some reason 4.5.3 wasn't installed, so I had used 4.5.  With 4.6 it seems to be working.

Comment: To check .net version, refer https://smartdoc.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205232308-How-to-check-your-NET-Framework-version